# What are the predicted consequences of quantum non-equilibrium besides the faster-than-light signaling?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics

It is [prdicted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_non-equilibrium) that quantum non-equilibrium can allow for faster-than-light signaling.

What are some other consequences of quantum non-equilibrium?

Is not [negative mass matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass), which also allows faster-than-light travel a manifestation of quantum equilibrium?

It is [argued](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.07840.pdf) that currently the world is in quantum equilibrium, which is similar to the heat death, but this may be violated in the presence of gravity.

But in the gravitational field of negative mass quantum fluctuations should be more intense, so the temperature of vacuum bigger? What about positive mass? Does more cool vacuum (due to time dilation) in gravity field represent an example of quantum non-equilibrium?